# Cannot ping anything from tun interface

Tags: openvpn, ping, ufw

I'm setting up a VPN server using OpenVPN server 2.4. The client connects to the server, but I can not seem to be able to ping any other host except the server or other clients on the VPN subnet. The server can be pinged by the local network address or the VPN server address.

Details:

- Local network: 192.168.1.0/24
- VPN network: 10.8.0.0/24
- Server IP: 192.168.1.7
- Server IP (VPN side): 10.8.0.1

I tried to ping some hosts from my server directly (with the tun0 interface), but cannot seem to ping any host whatsoever, not even the loopback address.

`ping -I tun0 216.58.208.163`
returns:

```
PING 216.58.208.163 (216.58.208.163) from 10.8.0.1 tun0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 216.58.208.163 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2041ms
```

This does the same for any other IP address. I have also tried to use traceroute on the tun0 interface, but that just returns asterisks.

I am also using a UFW firewall, with the following rules:

(/etc/ufw/before.rules):

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eno0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eno0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

`ufw allow out on tun0`

output of `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
```

When trying to ping, ufw.log outputs:

```
Apr  8 20:41:19 bester kernel: [5276818.036375] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=10.8.0.1 DST=216.58.208.163 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14804 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3815 SEQ=2
```

What am I doing wrong with my UFW rules or routing rules?